# Use a varible to make a table name in sql command text

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make an sql command text query in which i pass a variable named **m** as a part of the table name. This is what i have tried but seems not to be working :

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = 
'SELECT ProfileId, FloorId, ZoneId, mapHierarchyString, x, y 
FROM DynamicPosition'+@tableNumber+' 
WHERE ProfileId='''+@profileId+''';
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is interpreting the @m literally because it is within the quotes. Put it outside them and make the whole thing two strings:

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = "SELECT FloorId, ZoneId, FROM DynamicPosition" + @m + " WHERE ProfileId='WIFI5'";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax issue in the script. Try with this following scritp-

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = 
'
SELECT FloorId, ZoneId FROM DynamicPosition'+@m+'  
WHERE ProfileId='''+@profileId+''' AND FloorId = '+@floorId+'
';
--Assuming FloorId are Number
```

You code will be as below-

```
sqlCommand.CommandText = 
'SELECT ProfileId, FloorId, ZoneId, mapHierarchyString, x, y 
FROM DynamicPosition'+@tableNumber+' 
WHERE ProfileId='''+@profileId+'''';
```

Comment: profileId is a string the script above is not working on my side; could you please check again ? Thanks mate.

Comment: Hello Rabbani, I edited my script according to your script but visiual studio is showing some red lines errors which say ''Too may characters in character literal" . Check the script in the question post and let me know if there is something wrong. Thanks mate

Comment: @Xris, Please add one more single quote at the end of the script as - WHERE ProfileId='''+@profileId+''''; Also you can check the new code added in my answer.